# How to use Timestamp to get daily, monthly, and yearly transaction in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[Transaction Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qex6U.png)

How i can get all collection within a time period, like daily, monthly, and yearly?
And what a simple loop to count all the prices while getting all the field correspondent to the time period?

Or is that my collection is wrong and i need to separate them into year, month, and day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries only work with exact matches, or prefix matches for strings.  If you want query results for a particular year, month, or day, you will need to have a field for that specific year, month, or day in fields in your documents.